# How to find the circumference of a circle with an inputted area

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a code that will ask the user for the area of a circle, and from that find the circumference of it.

So far I have got this code:

```
area = input("Please choose an area for your circle: ")
def circumference(area):
    import math
    circumference = (squareRoot(area)) / (math.pi)

print("The circumference is: ", circumference)
```

When the chosen area is 60, it returns:

```
Please choose an area for your circle: 60
The circumference is:  <function circumference at 0x101478510>
```

How can I improve my code so that it works and why it would work?

Comment: `print("The circumference is: ", circumference(area))`. Also: `circumference = (squareRoot(area)) / (math.pi)` is not syntactically(and semantically) correct. Replace it by: `return squareRoot(area / math.pi) * 2 * math.pi`

Answer (score 3):

You must call the function (add parenthesis), pass it the `area` parameter, and return the result:
You also need to cast the input to a number (here, a float)
You should use `math.sqrt` instead of an undefined `SquareRoot` function

```
import math                                          # place imports at the top

def circumference(area):
    circ = (math.sqrt(float(area))) / (math.pi)      #<- cast param to float, use math.sqrt
    return circ                                      #<- return the result

area = input("Please choose an area for your circle: ")
print("The circumference is: ", circumference(area)) #<- call the function with a parameter
```

Alternatively, you could choose to cast the input to a float, before passing it as a parameter to the function:

```
import math                                          # place imports at the top

def circumference(area):
    circ = (math.sqrt(area)) / (math.pi)      #<- use math.sqrt
    return circ                                      #<- return the result

area = float(input("Please choose an area for your circle: ")) #<- cast param to float, 
print("The circumference is: ", circumference(area)) #<- call the function with a parameter
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in the parameter 'area' as a string. Try this...

```
area = int(input("Please choose an area for your circle: "))
```

This is necessary as you cannot use squareRoot on a string.

Also, the area of a circle is pi * r^2 whereas the circumference is 2 * pi * r.

This means you cannot just divide the square root of the area by pi.

Instead, you need do area divided by pi to get r^2. Square root this to get r. Multiply r by 2*pi to get the circumference.

```
import math

def circumference(area):
    return math.sqrt(area/math.pi)*math.pi*2

area = int(input("Please choose an area for your circle: "))
```

Hope this helps!